# Microsoft Access use table filter as where in SQL query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access Database with a lot of tables (including data for certain units) and a lot of queries. I have another table of units that I want to investigate.

For now the queries apply to all units in the tables.

My goal is depending on the filter that I select in the unit table, execute all my queries taking into account in the `where` clause that only these units can be shown.

So my table is for example (the actual table is 5000 records)

```
Unit   Detail
AA     1
BB     1
CC     3
```

If I filter in this table for Detail `1`, I want all my queries to add in the where clause:

```
Where Unit="AA" or Unit="BB"
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `WHERE Unit IN ('AA', 'BB')`?

Comment: yes, but then I have to manually add this text in all the queries. My goal is to automate that process.

Comment: Then create another table with the list of values you want and `JOIN ON Unit = ValidUnits.Unit`

Comment: One other option would be if all valid values for `Unit` are `AA, BB, CC,...ZZ`, then you could try something like `WHERE LEN(Unit) = 2 AND LEFT(Unit,1) = RIGHT(Unit,1)` That's not perfect because `11` or `$$` will also match, but it might work for your situation. Or you can use a regular expression, but I think you need VBA for that in Access.

Comment: I doubt AA, BB, CC are real values in table. If you filter for Detail 1, specifying Units seems redundant. I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I apply filter criteria to forms and reports.